# How to explain this result due to Pôlya

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, analyticity

How to explain this result due to Pôlya:

An entire function is determined uniquely by the inverse images, counting multiplicities of three distinct non omited values.

I cannot understand how this work!.

Comment: I don't know, but the reference is Bestimmung einer ganzen Funktion endlichen Geschlechts durch viererlei Stellen, Mathematisk Tiskrift 1921.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is there is a an anglish translation!

Comment: I don't know. But maybe if you do a websearch, you'll come across some English-language paper that references and discusses the Polya paper.